# Bulb Challenge in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The question goes "Light bulbs are connected by a wire. Each bulb has a switch associated with it, however due to faulty wiring, a switch also changes the state of all the bulbs to the right of current bulb. Given an initial state of all bulbs, find the minimum number of switches you have to press to turn on all the bulbs. You can press the same switch multiple times".

I found this answer online but I'm not 100% sure about what the ternary operator is doing in the loop. What is `var initial` and `var current` doing?

```
function bulbs(arr){
  var switched = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      var initial = arr[i] === 1,
          current = (switched % 2 === 1)? !initial:initial;
      if(current === false){
        switched++;
      }
    }
  return switched;
}
```

Comment: `initial` is equal to the boolean return of if the value of `arr[i]` equals 1. `current` is either true or false (since `initial` is a boolean). It will be the same as `initial` if the current value of `switched` divided by 2 yields a remainder of 1, otherwise it's the logical not operator, or `!` changes the boolean to the opposite.

Comment: But why use the modulus and look for a remainder?

Comment: How does switched % 2 help with the actual changing of data? I'm looking for the way its being used in the loop not a generic definition of what modulus does

Comment: This is clearly a question for some course/school. I think using this site is cheating. You  will learn more if you do the research on your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with an example: You are given 4 light bulbs at positions 0, 1, 2, 3; the second light bulb is switched on:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

You then iterate through the light bulbs from 0 to 3 and whenever you encounter a switched-off light bulb, you turn it on and you invert all switches to the right.

```
[1, 0, 1, 1] // Bulb 0 is switched on, bulb 1, 2 and 3 inverted
 ^

[1, 1, 0, 0] // Bulb 1 is switched on, bulb 2 and 3 inverted
    ^

[1, 1, 1, 1] // Bulb 2 is switched on, bulb 3 inverted
       ^ 

[1, 1, 1, 1] // Bulb 3 is on, do nothing
          ^
```

You needed to press three switches to turn all light bulbs on.

Let's now encode the above schema into a JavaScript function:

```
function bulbs(arr) {
  var switched = 0;

  // Iterate through light bulbs from left to right:
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var current = arr[i] === 1;               // True if bulb at position i is on
    if (current === false) {                  // It is off, so we press the switch
      switched++;
      for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {  // Invert all bulbs to the right
        arr[j] = arr[j] === 1 ? 0 : 1;        // Invert 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0
      }
    }
  }
  return switched;
}
```

This algorithm is correct, but it is slow. For each switch we press, we need to manually iterate through all bulbs on the right and invert them one by one. This algorithm has a worst-case runtime complexity of O(n²) where n is the number of light bulbs.

We can improve the performance by exploiting an important observation: The state of a light bulb at position `i` is predictably given by its initial state (on or off) and the number of times you pressed on any switch before reaching position `i`:

- If you pressed an even number of switches beforehand (0, 2, 4, ... times), its status equals its initial status.
- If you pressed an odd number of switches beforehand (1, 3, 5, ... times), its status equals the inverse of its initial status.

Now, you already store the number of switches you pressed in variable `switched`. In order to determine if `switched` is odd, you can use `switched % 2 === 1`. And if switched is odd, we have to invert the initial state of light bulb `i` to get its current state by performing `!initial`:

```
current = (switched % 2 === 1) ? !initial : initial;
```

This improved algorithm no longer features an inner for-loop and is therefore much faster with linear runtime complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach to the problem.

```
function solve(A, N) {
    // Initially no switches have been flipped
    var isFlipped = false;
    var ans = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // Case 1: If the array element is 0 and switches have not been flipped 
        // then it needs to be flipped to turn on the switch.
        // Case 2: If the array element is 1 and switches have been flipped 
        // then it means this value is actually 0 and hence it needs to be 
        // flipped again to turn on the switch.
        if (A[i] == 0 && !isFlipped || A[i] == 1 && isFlipped) {
            ans++;
            isFlipped = !isFlipped;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution is incorrect, you can try this special case:

> bulbs([2,3,4,1,5]); // returns: 3

and it returns 3. But the correct result should be 2 (includes: 1,5)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  It is certainly suitable as a comment, though.